# Effects of Deactivating An APK

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

I am trying to update native android app which was previously been built and uploaded by some other guys in some cross platform technology(Titanium). App was published in Advanced Mode where there was a different build for tablet and different for Phone. But now I have a single APK which works for both Phone and Tablet. So what happens if I deactivate those two builds and publish this new build to Play Store.

Does those users with old builds will get an update for my new Native App, considering I have higher Version Code?

Will there be any count decrements in the download counts and ratings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's published under the same package name as the previous apks, but with a higher version number, then devices with either of the previous apks will be prompted to update to the new one.

It will be treated as a normal upgrade of the app and will not reset any stats.